# How to fix "average" is not defined in google sheets script editor?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my own formula, but I don't know much about javascript, why am I getting an error code of "average" is not defined?

```
function myFunction(PLAYS,YARDS,TOUCHDOWNS,TURNOVERS) {
  return average(average(MEDIAN(0,1,((YARDS/PLAYS-5)/9)),MEDIAN(0,1,(TOUCHDOWNS)*6/PLAYS),median(0,1,1-(TURNOVERS)/(PLAYS/9))),median(0,1,average(median(0,1,(YARDS-100)/450),median(0,1,(TOUCHDOWNS)/7),median(0,1,1-(TURNOVERS)/8))))
}
```

I have tried adding "return" at the beginning, capitalizing everything, but I don't really know where to start

Comment: It means there is no function available called `average`.

Answer (score 0):

There is not such function as `average`, especially capitalised. You can find all `Math` functions available in JS here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

There also is no median method and you rather should not capitalise params in JS.

You can create your own functions that takes arrays as arguments,  example:

```js
function average(arr){
 return arr.reduce(function(sum, next){
   return sum + next
  }) / arr.length
}

function median (arr){
 var sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return a - b
  }) 
 var mediumIndex = Math.floor(sortedArr.length/2)
 var result;
  if(mediumIndex === sortedArr.length){
    result = sortedArr[mediumIndex]
  }
  else{
     result = (sortedArr[mediumIndex] + sortedArr[mediumIndex + 1] / 2)
  }
  return result
}

x =[1,2,3,5,6]
console.log(average(x))
console.log(median(x))
```

Comment: So how do I make my formula return the average and median for the formula I put in?